# How to extract data from a dataset using regex in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset and I would like to extract the appositive feature from this dataset.

```
در
همین
حال
،
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
نجیب
 الله
خواجه
عمری
 ,
 </coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="atr">
سرپرست
وزارت
تحصیلات
عالی
افغانستان
</coref>
گفت
که
در
سه
ماه
گذشته
در
۳۳
ولایت
کشور
<coref coref_coreftype="ident" coref_coref_class="empty" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref">
خدمات
ملکی
</coref>
از
حدود
۱۴۹
هزار
```

I want to store the data inside dataset in two list. In `find_atr` list I stored the data where the coref tag includes `coref_coreftype="atr"`. For the `find_ident` list I want to store the data of `coref_coreftype="ident"` So we have on the last coref tag in this dataset another coref tag that has `coref_coref_class="empty"`. I dont want to store that data that has the tag `coref_coref_class="empty"`. Now on the regex I mentioned that it should only include those that the `coref_coref_class="set_.*?"` not `coref_coref_class="empty"` but it still store the data of `coref_coref_class="empty"`, where it should only store the `coref_coref_class="set_.*?"`.

How to avoid:

```
i_ident = []
j_atr = []
find_ident = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set_.*?coref_mentiontype="ne".*?coref_coreftype="ident".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)
ident_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_ident))
for i in range(len(ident_list)):
    i_ident.append(str(ident_list[i]))

find_atr = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coreftype="atr".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)
atr_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_atr))
#print(coref_list)
for i in range(len(atr_list)):
    j_atr.append(str(atr_list[i]))

print(i_ident)
print()
print(j_atr)
```

Comment: What you have looks like XML, so using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) might work.

Comment: @Lomtrur, it is not an XML file. it was based on MMAX2 and I convert it using salt. now my file has this structure. what is wrong with the regex? why it includes the coref_coref_class="empty"

Comment: I see this line `find_atr = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coreftype="atr".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)` just verify the type but it will retrieve any class. I'm not sure if that is the problem

Comment: @GVelascoh, the find_atr=.... working well, it retrieve only those that have the 'coref_coreftype="atr"'. The problem is with find_ident = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set_.*?coref_mentiontype="ne".*?coref_coreftype="ident".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S) that extract from last line of the dataset where the coref_coref_class="empty", and I mentioned in find_indent that only extract coref_coref_class="set_". this is the problem that why it extract for the 'empty' class.

Comment: I don’t understand your description, could you provide desired output?

Comment: @pacholik, look the dataset, I want to store that data inside dataset in two list. In find_atr list I stored the data where the coref tag includes 'coref_coreftype="atr"'. For the find_ident list I want to store the data of 'coref_coreftype="ident"' So we have on the last coref tag in this dataset another coref tag that 'coref_coref_class="empty"'. I dont want to store that data of those who has the tag 'coref_coref_class="empty"'. Now on the regex I mentioned that it should only include those that the 'coref_coref_class="set_.*?"' not 'coref_coref_class="empty"' but it still store that.

Comment: Please specify how `read_dataset` variable is created to be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @GVelascoh, `read_dataset` is a variable that read the dataset file. It does not create any problem. The only problem is with the last `coref tag` in the example above. Because it has `coref_coref_class="empty"` and in `find_indent` I mentioned that the `coref_coref_class="set_.*?` but still it extract from last tag that has `coref_coref_class="empty"`.

Comment: @GVelascoh, look at this regex, `find_ident = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set_.*?coref_mentiontype="ne".*?coref_coreftype="ident".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)`, it means to extract from those line that has `coref_coref_class="set_.*?` but not `coref_coref_class="empty"`, my question is why it also include `empty class`, where I did not included inside my regex.

Comment: I tried your code and got this output, which seems ok for me, am I right?:`[' نجیب  الله خواجه عمری  ,  ']`and `[' سرپرست وزارت تحصیلات عالی افغانستان ']`

Comment: @GVelascoh, if `[' نجیب الله خواجه عمری , ']` was inside `find_ident` list and `['رپرست وزارت تحصیلات عالی افغانستان '] ` in `find_atr, then the output is fine. In this case my code also store that data of `<coref coref_coreftype="ident" coref_coref_class="empty" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref">
خدمات
ملکی
</coref> ` inside `find_ident` which is not correct, because the `coref_coref_class="empty"` in this tag. So I dont want to store the data of `coref_coref_class="empty"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced your dataset file to:

```
A
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
B
</coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="atr">
C
</coref>
D
<coref coref_coreftype="ident" coref_coref_class="empty" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref">
E
</coref>
F
```

And tried this code, which is almost the same you provided:

```
import re

with open ("test_dataset.log", "r") as myfile:
    read_dataset = myfile.read()

i_ident = []
j_atr = []
find_ident = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set_.*?coref_mentiontype="ne".*?coref_coreftype="ident".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)
ident_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_ident))
for i in range(len(ident_list)):
    i_ident.append(str(ident_list[i]))

find_atr = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coreftype="atr".*?>(.*?)</coref>', read_dataset, re.S)
atr_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_atr))
#print(coref_list)
for i in range(len(atr_list)):
    j_atr.append(str(atr_list[i]))

print(i_ident)
print()
print(j_atr)
```

And got this output, which seems right to me:

```
[' B ']

[' C ']
```

Comment: I tried your dataset, and it works but again when I tried with my dataset, it gives the same as the previous result. I don't know why

Comment: When you said your dataset, is that a longer file or the same in the question post?. Could be that a nested tags issue?

Comment: Yes, it is 5K words annotated for the task of coreference resolution. The file has the same structure as I post it here. And if it is the nested tag issue why it can extract for the `coref_coreftype="atr"`.

Comment: You can include the matching lines in the output to verify which lines are matching the regex, and also that there are not nested or unexpected tags in your file

Comment: Thank you, I will try that too. Can we change the structure of the regex but I dont have anything in my mind.

Comment: I will suggest you to do a grep on the file looking for "empty", to check if there exist any unexpected pattern with a class containing "empty".

Comment: Thank you very much, with grep it gives me the result. but it gives empty list for those that not included in the regex. for example find_indent[3]  is empty. How to filter the empty entities, because now I am working to match j if it is attributive of i.

Comment: This is the output for the `find_indent`: `['', ' نجیب الله خواجه عمری , ', '', '', ' محمد میرویس بلخی ', '', '', '', ' محمد نادر نادری ', '', '', '', '', '', ' رئیس جمهور غنی ', '', '', '', ' رئیس جمهور غنی ', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' جنرال محمد رادمنش ', '', '', '', '', '', ' جنگجویان داعش ', '', '', ' واسیلی نِبِنزیا ', '', '', '', '', ' افغانستان ', '', '', '', ' طالبان ', '', '', '', '', ' جنرال محمد رادمنش ', '', '', '', '', '', ' این جنبش ', '', ' طالبان ']`