# How to use categorical data in decision tree in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset from which I have extracted 12 features for the task of coreference resolution using decision trees. Some examples of these features are:

- distance_feature(): distance between i and j according to the number of sentences. output: 0 or 1

  - Ispronoun_feature(): this feature is set to true if a noun phrase is a pronoun.
  - appositive_feature(): This feature checks if `j` is in apposition of `i`.

After creating all these features to extract the results from the dataset I don't know how to select the root node or how to use the sci-kit learn decision tree algorithm because the data is not structured and is categorical. A paper I read mentionned entropy and information gain but all the example of these two attributes are based on a structured dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you have diverse features of different categories, and don't want to spend time on encoding them yourself, I would recommend using the [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/) framework which is also faster than the standard scikit implementations of trees.

Check this [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/pacifik80/yandex-catboost-demo) for implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Use one-hot encoding.

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, [categorical_columns_you_want_to_encode])
```

If there ended up to be too many columns, you can preprocess your column to drop values that are not as common - e.g less than 1% to avoid having too many columns.

Comment: Actually the data is not structured I extract the data for i and j as below: i = [' نجیب الله خواجه عمری ', ' محمد میرویس بلخی ', ' محمد نادر نادری ', ' محمد اشرف غنی ', ' رئیس جمهور غنی ', ' رئیس جمهور غنی ', ' اعضای کاروان صلح هلمند ', ' این کاروان ', ' سرپرست دفتر سخنگوی این وزارت ', ' وی ', ' آنان ', ' نمایندۀ دایمی روسیه ', ' افغانستان ', ' طالبان ', ' جنرال محمد رادمنش ', ' محمداشرف غنی '] and the value of j= [' سرپرست وزارت تحصیلات عالی افغانستان ', ' سرپرست زارت معارف افغانستان]

Comment: Then I created 12 features for these values of `i` and `j`. Therefore, each feature has it is own output based on features specification

Comment: umm. if you want to train one model I'm pretty sure the way would be to structurize this data, e.g putting all data in the same dataframe, instead of just having the unique categories. Basically, going back to the source data and extract them on the basis of one row -> one label.

Comment: Actually the task is to extract from unstructured data. so It is so complex to change the dataset. as we have only for some of the text the lable with different attributes.

Comment: The idea of classification is based on 1 event -> 1 result. You'll need to extract from the dataset the events, and since you identified 12 features, each event will have 12 columns and 1 result (or more), put them in a dictionary or array or pandas table and sklearn can take care of the rest.

Comment: You mean I put the output of each feature into a table.

Comment: each event will have a feature, I don't know what you mean by output - you'll need to identify feature for *each* event, and if you can't for a certain event because it's not there, fill it with `None`.

Comment: For your information, I have already posted the structure of my dataset in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755539/how-to-extract-data-from-a-dataset-using-regex-in-python?noredirect=1#comment92437883_52755539) and I stored first the value of i and j based on this dataset and then implemented the 12 features. that is why it is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: And if you see this [link](https://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/cs224n/2008/reports/18.pdf), I created the featured based on this paper.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what predictions are for - it seems there are multiple per paper and I don't entirely understand there point - I think I have to stop here - they are also using a very old package. `whereas sklearn.DecisionTreeClassifier` has a *very clear* instruction of how to use, what data to pass in -> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit